# Exclude word from string.Split

Tags: css

I'm new in css and I have pure hamburguer css menu

Problem is the menu is part of page as `absolute` item, I want it to `float` and show always when page scroll, the position is just bellow header

[image]

Desire result:

[image]

And when menu is open take space of page and show an icon at the bottom of menu:

[image: r m x]

Snippet:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin:0px;
}

.section-title{
    color: #2ddf5c;
    }


.main-header{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-evenly;
width:100%;
/* background: #2ddf5c; */
padding: 16px;
}

.main-header > div{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.main-header__brand{
color: #7B8F34;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
}

.main-nav__searchbar_container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.main-nav__searchbar_container input.main-nav__searchbar{
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
  /* background: #2b303b; */
  border: none;
  font-size: 10pt;
  float: left;
  /* color: #fff; */
  padding-left: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.main-nav__searchbar_container input.main-nav__searchbar::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: #65737e;
}

.main-nav__searchbar_container input.main-nav__searchbar:-moz-placeholder{ /*Frefox 18 */
    color: #65737e;
}
.main-nav__searchbar_container input.main-nav__searchbar::-moz-placeholder{/*Frefox 19 */
    color: #65737e;
}
.main-nav__searchbar_container input.main-nav__searchbar:-ms-input-placeholder{
    color: #65737e;
}
.main-nav__searchbar_container button.icon{
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    background: #4f5b66;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 10pt;
    -webkit-transition: all .55s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .55s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .55s ease;
    -o-transition: all .55s ease;
    transition: all .55s ease;
  }

  .main-nav__searchbar_container:hover button.icon,
  .main-nav__searchbar_container:active button.icon,
  .main-nav__searchbar_container:focus button.icon{
      outline: none;
      opacity: 1;
      margin-left: -50px;
  }

.main-nav__searchbar_container:hover button.icon:hover{
    background: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input.main-nav__searchbar:hover{
    border: 2px solid #4f5b66;
}
.main-nav__searchbar{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    /* margin: 8px; */
    /* padding: 8px; */
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
    transition: .3s;
}

.main-nav{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.main-nav__items{
display: flex;
margin:8px;
padding:8px;
list-style: none;
}
.main-nav__item{
    display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav__social{
    display:block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 4px;
}



#main-slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 528px;
    /* border-radius: 0% 0% 50% 50% / 0% 0% 20% 20%; */
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 25%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 25%;
    position: relative;
}

.badge {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 35px 0 rgba(42,51,83,.12), 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
  }

  .text {
    padding: 0.5rem 0.25rem 0.5rem 1rem;
  }

  .link {
    border-radius: inherit;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: #7B8F34;
   padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    color: #F9F9EC;
  }

  .slider-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }




  /* menu */

.main .menu {
  clear: both;
  /* max-height: 0; */
  display: none;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.main .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.main .menu-icon .nav-icon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.main .menu-icon .nav-icon:before,
.main .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.main .menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.main .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

/* menu btn */

.main .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.main .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  /* max-height: 240px; */
  display: block;
}

.main .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon {
  background: transparent;
}

.main .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top:0;
}

.main .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top:0;
}



@media (min-width: 48em) {
  
  .main li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .main .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
            <div>
                <a href="index.html" class="main-header__brand">
                    uHost
                </a></div><nav class="main-nav">
                    <div class=main-nav__searchbar_container><input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="main-nav__searchbar">
                    <button class="icon"><i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </div>
                <ul class="main-nav__items">
                    <li class="main-nav__item"> 
                        <img class="main-nav__social" src="navbar-icons/social-media__icons/facebook.svg" alt="facebook">
                    </li>
                    <li class="main-nav__item">
                        <img class="main-nav__social" src="navbar-icons/social-media__icons/instagram-bosquejado.svg" alt="instagram">
                    </li>  
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="main">
          <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
            <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="nav-icon"></span></label>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#test1">Test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#test2">Test2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#test3">Test3</a></li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        <main> 
          
            <section>
                <div class="slider-wrapper">
                  <img id="main-slider" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1365x528?text=Slider">
                </div>
              </section>
```

Regards

Comment: How is this `c#` and `string` related? Please remove and add proper tags to the post. Also, where is the split you're talking about in your actual title?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Float hamburguer menu css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63769893/float-hamburguer-menu-css)

Comment: try adding a z-index of 100 to class main-nav it will work hope so.